# .htaccess: redirect specific link to another?

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

I have these three links:

```
localhost/my_projects/my_website.php
localhost/my_projects/my_website.html
localhost/my_projects/my_website
```

The paths of the php and html files are as follows:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\my_projects\my_website.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\my_projects\my_website.html
```

The link without an extension is "artificial" and I want to use said link:

```
localhost/my_projects/my_website
```

to get the contents of either of these links:

```
localhost/my_projects/my_website.php
localhost/my_projects/my_website.html
```

The reason for the two example files, instead of just one, is that I want to be able to switch between those two files when I edit the htaccess file. Obviously I only want to access one of those files at a time.

What do I need to have in my .htaccess file inside the my_projects folder to accomplish that? How can I make one specific link redirect to another specific link?

Comment: Can you add the current .htaccess to the question?

Comment: @Juan It's basically empty. I tried many things, but none of them worked. The folder im trying to manipulate (my own folder, my_projects) didn't have an .htaccess file before.

Comment: which is the document root?

Comment: Well, it's localhost. I have my xampp saved in C:/, so I assume the document root is C:\xampp\htdocs, where my "my_projects" folder is... sorry if I'm being stupid, does that info help?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment clarifying your folder structure I corrected the RewriteRule. (By the way, it would be best if you add that info to the question itself instead of in comments).

The url you want to target is: `http://localhost/my_projects/my_website`

`http://` is the protocol
`localhost` is your domain (it could also be 127.0.0.1 or a domian name like `www.example.com` in the Internet)

I assume you are running Apache on port `80`, otherwise in the url you need to also specify the port. For port `8086` for example it would be `http://localhost:8086/my_projects/my_website`.

The real path is `htdocs/my_projects/my_website.php` or `htdocs/my_projects/my_website.html` depending on your needs (obviously both won't work at the same time).

Here the `my_projects` in the "fake" url collides with the real folder `"my_projects"` so Apache will go for the folder and see there is no my_website (with no extension) document there (it won't reach the rewrite rules).

There is a question in SO that provides a work around for this, but it is not a perfect solution, it has edge cases where the url will still fail or make other urls fail. I had posted it yesterday, but I seem not to find it now.

The simple solution if you have the flexibility for doing it is to change the "fake" url for it not to collide with the real path.

One option is for example to replace the underscores with hyphens.
Then you would access the page as `http://localhost/my-projects/my-website` if you want to keep a sort of "fake" folder structure in the url. Otherwise you could simply use `http://localhost/my-website`.

Here are both alternatives:

```
# This is for the directory not to be shown. You can remove it if you don't mind that happening.
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

#Rule for http://localhost/my-projects/my-website
RewriteRule ^my-projects/my-website(.+)?$ my_projects/my_website.php$1 [NC,L]

#Rule for http://localhost/my-website
RewriteRule ^my-website(.+)?$ my_projects/my_website.php$1 [NC,L]
```

(Don't use both, just choose one of these two, or use them to adapt it to your needs)

The first part the rewrite rule is the regular expression for your "fake" url, the second part is the relative path of your real folder structure upto the page you want to show.

In the regular expression we capture whatever what we assume to be possible query parameters after `.../my_website`, and paste it after `my_website.php` in the second part of the rule (the `$1`).

Later on if you want to point the url to `my_website.html`, you have to change the second part of the rule, where it says `.php`, replace it by `.html`.

By the way, it is perfectly valid and you'll see it in most `SEO` friendly web sites to write an url as `http://www.somesite.com/some-page-locator`, and have a rewrite rule that translates that url to a page on the website, which is what I had written in my first answer.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179990/discussion-between-noclue-and-juan).

Comment: [My reaction when I finally figured it out.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3ALwKeSEYs) It was supposed to be: RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^my_website/?$ my_website.php [NC,L]